# BigCommerce - Feature Products > Descriptions

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm using Bigcommerce and on the homepage, I pull through the Featured Products  which is easily done (via `%%Panel.HomeFeaturedProducts%%`). The hard part is I want to also pull through those specific feature products descriptions or trimmed descriptions.

`%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%` does not work at all in `Snippets/HomeFeaturedProductsItems.html` file.

Can someone please advise on this?

Answer (score 1):

`%%GLOBAL_ProductSummary%%` variable is what you are after.

It contains trimmed product description (120 characters max)

Comment: Oh my god thank you so very much. Works perfectly, exactly what was doing my head in for 2 days now

Comment: No worries! Just make sure you accept the answer ;-) Thanks